# Jquery resizable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this html div

```
<div id="CropToolDiv"></div>
```

And this Jquery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#CropToolDiv').draggable();
    $('#CropToolDiv').resizable();
});
</script>
```

But it gives an error

```
$(...).draggable is not a function
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put your code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#CropToolDiv').draggable();
    $('#CropToolDiv').resizable();
});
</script>
```

At the bottom of the page..  See -- It works here

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vcL5tptx/)

Comment: If this solves, or doesn't solve your problem, please comment or accept my answer :-)